# Parameter Passing from ExtJs to Html

Tags: html, extjs, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass an Extjs parameter ,which I retrieved from a store in the code, to html code.

Any ideas?

Comment: No - no ideas... I do not even understand, what you're trying to do.

Comment: Um, yeah. You need to explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

ok.so here is the structure.

I am trying to make an ajax call with `updater.update` from jsp.

The call goes to controller and returns a jsp which includes another jsp(jsp include is used)

the jsp ,which is included by the other one, needs an attribute which is on a store object. So I need to fetch it from the store and place it on the html side.

Is it more clear now?

Thanks for your replies

PS: Actually my real problem is: the jsp ,which is included by the other jsp,  includes scripts and as I have read from the responses on internet,  to call a jsp page(which includes javascripts) through ajax and try to render it, is not possible on ie7 and ie 8(the famous "Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101" error ). Is it correct?